# Mercurial - execute as other user

Tags: linux, bash, mercurial

I use a mercurial repository for global configuration. The system config files are linked to /opt/config which is a hg repo owned by root.

I d like all users to be able to update settings from repo i.e. to call `hg pull -u` in `/opt/config`

I tried to create the following script

```
# -rwsr-x--x 1 root users 343 Mar 15 14:10 /bin/update_config

#! /bin/bash
cd /opt/config
hg pull -u
```

(Pay attention, the s-bit is set) . In this case, `hg` does not read the settings from `/root/.hgrc` which contain the HTTP login parameter (user cannot does not know the parameters)

even if I do `export HOME=/root` the `hgrc` file is not read.

How should I change my script to make it possible?

**EDIT**

It seems to be a general permission problem. I use sles11. The line `touch /root/bla` does not work in this script, why?

Comment: You cannot setuid shell scripts.

Comment: Why not? I thought that's what the s-bit is for?

Comment: Yes, that’s what it’s for. But shells deliberately undo its effect because of the (possible) security hazard.

Comment: Is there any shell that does not undo the effect?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial being a distributed versioning system, it seems to me that you are not using it correctly. If users are required to modify the repository, every user should handle its own repository and then configure it to `push` into your desired location (`/opt/config`). Hence, the mercurial workflow will handle the merge problems. If they are only consumers of the repository, you should either 1) create a cron entry to update it automatically or 2) use a continuous integration system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) that will automatically update the repository when something is pushed to it.

If you still want to realize what you asked, you should look into the `sudo` command for this purpose. Make the /opt/config ownership to a new passwordless user, configure `sudo` to allow the switch to this user without password and make the configuration only in  ~theuser/.hgrc . This will make it easier to maintain (only a single .hgrc to handle).

Comment: That's the point: The users are all consumers. If I try to create a cron job, users won't be able to see their config changes immediately on the machine -> no one will check in the settings.
I don't want to install Jenkins nor TeamCity